# why do the individual parts of this function work on their own but the function as a whole fails?

Tags: javascript

If I copy and paste each part of this function everything works. However when I try to use the function on its own I get:

```
VM7192:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

My function is:

```
var read_f = function() {
    var restext = $.get('file.txt');
    var text = restext.responseText;
    text = text.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g);
    text = text.join('').split(/Q0/);
    return text;
};
```

What's happening ?

Comment: `$.get` returns a [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object. Such an object doesn't have a `responseText` property. Hence `text` is `undefined` and `undefined.match()` throws an error because `undefined` doesn't have such a method.

Comment: `$.get` uses AJAX.  AJAX is *asynchronous*.  You cannot return a value from an AJAX call.  You need to use callbacks.

Comment: @FelixKling not sure I understand...for example, this doesn't work out for me https://jsfiddle.net/gf8pq135/

Comment: The first argument passed to `success` is already the response text, so you need `var textres = data;` or directly access `data`. See the documentation:  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/